# Scheme's version of C's `++`

Tags: increment, chicken-scheme

How would I go about incrementing a variable, that is doing something like `a=0; a++;` in **Chicken**?

In Common Lisp I'd do this using `incf` like so:

```
(setf a 0) (incf a) (print a)

;=> 0

;=> 1

;=> 1
;=> 1
```

But Chicken-scheme doesn't seem to have a `incf` function/macro, and I've tried using the `apropos` egg thingy, but that hasn't helped at all so far.

In C, I'd increment the variable like so:

```
int a = 0;
a++;
printf("%d", a);
```

**NOTE**, I don't want to know how to simply increase the value of `a` temporarily by `1`, I want to increment `a` so that `a` no longer equals `0` but equals `1`.

Thus, the following is **NOT** what I want:

```
(let ((a 0)) (set! a (+ 1 a)) (print a))
```

Here's an example of what I'm looking for--written in NewLisp:

```
(set 'a 0) (++ a) (println a)
```

**NOTE**
The function/macro needs to be able to accept a quoted variable and increment that variables value, permanently.  Thus it needs to be equivalent to the following C code:

```
a = 0; a++; // a now equals 1
```

I'd just write a macro to do this in Chicken, but I can't seem to make heads or tails of the Chicken's macros--they just don't make any sense; they're nothing like common-lisps macros at all.

Here's an example macro that I just hacked together in common-lisp:

```
(defmacro ++ (sym) (let ((a (gensym "a,sym,") ))
  `(let* ((,a ,sym))
      (setf ,sym (+ 1 ,a)) ,sym)) )

(setf a 0)

;=> 0

(++ a)

;=> 1

a 

;=> 1
```

Comment: **NOTE** If I can't do this `(set! a 0) (SOME-FUNCTION-OR-MACRO a) (print a)` and get `1` back from `(print a)` then it isn't what I want.

Comment: i edited my answer. check.

Comment: Svante's answer is correct (and you should tell him why you think it isn't), but if you don't want to copy his macro into your code, it is available in the miscmacros egg (with the same name, inc!). That version, like incf in CL, has an optional second argument that let's you say by how much to increment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting things is done with `set!` in Scheme.

```
(let ((a 0))
  (set! a (+ a 1))
  (print a))
```

I am not a Schemer, but I think you can write a macro for this like the following:

```
(define-syntax inc!
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((inc! var)
     (set! var (+ var 1)))))
```

so that you can then write

```
(inc! a)
```

Comment: not what I want.  I want something that's like common-lisp's `incf`

Comment: That is, if I can't do this `(set! a 0) (SOME-FUNCTION-OR-MACRO a) (print a)` and get `1` back from `(print a)` then it isn't what I want.

Comment: again in this : if you have (SOME-FUNCTION a) a variable is SHADOWED in SOME-FUNCTIONs body. If you however explicitly change the *global* a, as in my example , it would work. Now as you see Svante didn't create a function, but a syntax. So SOME-FUNCTION is really different from SOME-MACRO.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define counter
        (let ((count 0))
          (lambda ()
            (set! count (+ count 1))
            count)))

>(counter)
1
>(counter)
2
```

Always keep the scope of your side-effects contained within closures.
the count variable can't escape the `let` scope

EDIT:
please look at the following. (Although it is exactly what you should try to usually avoid!)

```
> (define a 0)
> (define inca (lambda () (set! a (+ a 1))))
> a
0
> (inca)
> a
1
```

[SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) is a great book. You should try and understand the scope of variables in scheme and how it differs from other lisps. And being chicken scheme has NOTHING to do with these questions. Chicken is a great R5RS implementation and your questions would apply to all schemes.

Comment: I want the side-effect to persist beyond the scope of the incrementing-function.  I'll add more to my original post.

Comment: It would be worth noting that for all that I knew at the time that I asked my original question, every single implementation of scheme could have had a variant of `++`, *except* Chicken--I didn't know whether the question was applicable to every implementation of scheme or not because asking such a question was beyond the scope of what I was interested in.  All I wanted was to know how to do `X` in Chicken-scheme; not whether you couldn't do `X` in any scheme.